# How to use sort V horizontally?

Tags: linux, sorting, command-line

I have this table:

```
flame#43    king#402    Picnic#51   Sar#360     far#66  
flame#61    king#63     Picknic#67  Sar#66      far#65  
flame#63    king#60     Packnic#69  Sar#64      far#58
```

My desired output is:

```
flame#43  Picnick#51 far#66     Sar#360  king#402     

flame#61  king#63    far#65     Sar#66   Picknic#67

far#58    king#60    flame#63   Sar#64   Packnic#69
```

Does anyone know how to sort horizontally based on value when we have a text also?

I tried to used sort -V in variable combinations \with combination with  sort kn  .Also I tried to modified this code

```
awk ' {split( $0, a, " " ); asort( a ); 
for( i = 1; i <= length(a); i++ ) printf( "%s ", a[i] ); 
printf( "\n" ); }'
```

which sorts tables only when we have a numeric value table horizontally.

Comment: 1. Transpose. 2. Sort vertically. 3. Transpose again. `sort -V` sorts using version sort.. You want to sort each line separately?

Comment: yes but based on the value, not based on the "text"

Comment: Ok. then create another associative array indexes with the text with values with the numbers of the text. Like `for (i in a) { extract_number_from_a[i]; array2[ a[i] ] = the_number; }`. Then sort that another array and print it's indexes in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `asort` with your own comparison function

```
awk 'function trailing_number_compare(i1, v1, i2, v2,    _a, _l, _r, _n)
{
    _n = split(v1, _a, "#");
    _l = 0 + _a[2];

    _n = split(v2, _a, "#");
    _r = 0 + _a[2];

    if (_l < _r)
        return -1
    else if (_l == _r)
        return 0
    else
        return 1
}

{
    split($0, a, FS);
    n = asort(a, b, "trailing_number_compare");
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}' "$@"
```

The input from the question

```
flame#43    king#402    Picnic#51   Sar#360     far#66  
flame#61    king#63     Picknic#67  Sar#66      far#65  
flame#63    king#60     Packnic#69  Sar#64      far#58
```

results in this output

```
flame#43 Picnic#51 far#66 Sar#360 king#402 
flame#61 king#63 far#65 Sar#66 Picknic#67 
far#58 king#60 flame#63 Sar#64 Packnic#69
```

The function `trailing_number_compare` is based on the example in https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html

The function arguments starting with `_` are used as local variables.

Explanation:

- `function trailing_number_compare(i1, v1, i2, v2,    _a, _l, _r, _n) { ...}`
  Define a function to be passed to `asort` for user-defined comparison of two items. It will get arguments index 1 `i1`, value 1 `v1`, index 2 `i2` and value 2 `v2`. The other arguments will not be set by the caller and are used as local variables in the function.
- `_n = split(v1, _a, "#");`
  split `v1` into array `_a` at delimiter `"#"`, `_n` will be the number of fields and could be used for checking or iterating over the array.
- `_l = 0 + _a[2];`
  assign 2nd field to `_l`. Adding 0 forces numeric context.
- Similar for `v2` and `_r`...
- Finally do the comparison of `_l` and `_r`, the return value is used by `asort`

The action to be executed with all input lines is very similar to the original code, except that I use `FS` (field separator) to split the input and call `asort`with input and output array and the user defined comparison function.

Comment: It tooks me some time to understand the entire code but finally I did. Thanks also for the reference and for the code.!!!

Answer (score 1):

I used `asorti` function to sort an array where indexes are the numbers extracted from the elements. I filled the elements with leading zeros, because `asorti` sorts lexically not numerically. After sorting, I just print elements.

```
awk '{
    split($0, a, " ");

    for (i in a) {
        # extract number
        v = a[i]
        gsub(/.*#/, "", v)
        # because asorti sorts alphabetically, I fill indexes with zeros
        b[sprintf("%020d", v)] = a[i]
    }

    # sort using indexes
    n = asorti(b, dest)

    # output
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", b[dest[i]], i == n ? "\n" : " "
    }

    # if we dont delete b, it will only grow. So delete it.
    delete b
}' <<'EOF'
flame#43    king#402    Picnic#51   Sar#360     far#66  
flame#61    king#63     Picknic#67  Sar#66      far#65  
flame#63    king#60     Packnic#69  Sar#64      far#58
EOF
```

outputs:

```
flame#43 Picnic#51 far#66 Sar#360 king#402
flame#61 king#63 far#65 Sar#66 Picknic#67
far#58 king#60 flame#63 Sar#64 Packnic#69
```

I tested on [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php). You can pipe the output to `column -t -s ' ' -o ' '` to have the columnized output or do it in `awk` like with `printf "%-9s%s"`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I run it locally in command and works perfectly.